# xorg: New Monitor, Mouse Cursor too big

Tags: xorg, cursor

I bought a new Monitor today, and when I connected it, the mouse cursor becomes bigger (about 1.5 times the size) when I hover over any GUI window. When I move it over the Xorg background, it reverts to regular size.

What I have done so far to debug the issue:

- My .config/gtk-2.0/settings.ini and .config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini do not contain any cursor theme
- I tried to set a cursor theme using gnome-tweak-tool, but it doesn't get applied (yes, I've restarted my X session)
- The issue applies all X11 apps, no matter if it's GTK, QT or plain X11
- xdpyinfo reports 96x96, and setting xrandr --dpi 96 for all outputs individually doesn't help
- I run the i3 window manager on Debian Jessie

My Question is: How do I debug this issue best? Is there any way to have Xorg tell me which cursor theme it's using?

Comment: Do you have hardware cursor enabled on your graphic card? If yes, try disabling it.

Comment: I just tried both HWCursor and SWCursor, and the effect is identical.

Comment: I've found the same issue, xmonad on gentoo...

Comment: I'm having the same issue with xmonad on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I run i3 in xfce on Arch Linux on a laptop. Whenever I connected a my large monitor to extend my desktop I was getting the same behaviour.

I just discovered that by playing with the cursor size settings (through xfce's GUI, in my case) that this problem disappeared, at least for now.

I have connected and disconnected the monitor and the setting seems to have stuck. I don't know what a restart will do.